# File upload with json/ajax and HttpPut service with Asp.net 4.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, file-upload

I have looked at more than 100 posts about file upload now and am getting very confused without having found what I´m looking for.

Client side is pretty clear: I want to use ajax/json to PUT or POST a file (whichever is best) to the server. I want to send path and filename with the post, hence specifying this in the query, something like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/myService/PostFile",
        data: "fileName=" + this.fileName() + 
              "& path=" + this.filePath() +
              "& file=" + this.datafile,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,   
        success: function () {
           this.filePosted(true);
        }
    });
```

this.fileName(), this.filePath() being ko.observables.

Serverside is my biggest headache though. I need to define a serviceController, calling :

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostFile(string name, string path, byte[] file data)
    {
        var filename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + path + "/" + filename);

        // Then something like:
        FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(filename);
        fs.Write(filedata, 0, filedata.Length);
        fs.Close();

        return;
    }
```

I feel I´m on very thin ice here and am asking for directions. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try something like following - http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/uploading-files-asynchronously-using-asp.net-web-api.htm

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, @Jalpesh! 
After some finger trouble with the setup of my Route.mapper I managed to get this code to run. 
My route mapper is configured with  "{controller}/{action}", hence I had to change the ajax.url to  "url: "/API/FileUpload/PostAsync". Now it works. Brilliant and a 1000 thanx!!! :D